# Flexible JAXB XML parsing for generics and a particular type or a list of that type

Tags: java, xml, generics, jaxb, generic-programming

I am working with a colleague's API. The API returns a `Response` with a list of objects or just one, singular object. The objects can be of multiple types. The return type is in XML. I am interested in parsing this XML via JAXB to get my classes, ideally in a flexible and generic way.

The following two XML responses are a sample of what I am speaking about.

Sample 1: A response with a list `Jobs` containing `Job` object.

```
<Response>
   <Status>OK</Status>
   <Jobs>
        <Job>
            <ID>J1</ID>
            <Name>job name</Name> 
        </Job>
        <Job>
            <ID>J2</ID>
            <Name>job name</Name> 
        </Job>
    </Jobs>
</Response>
```

Sample 2: A response with one `Job`.

```
<Response>
    <Status>OK</Status> 
    <Job>
        <ID>J123</ID> 
        <Name>job name</Name> 
    </Job>
</Response>
```

At the moment, I am constructing something as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Response")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Response {
    @XmlElement(name = "Status")
    protected Status status;
    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    protected Object items;
}
```

Unmarshalling via

```
   Response = (Response) unmarshaller.unmarshal(myXmlResponse);
```

But I'm receiving `null` in my items when unmarshalling `Sample 1`. Also, this approach gives me a bad feeling as I'm using `Object` as a catch-all i.e. expecting both `List<Job>` and `Job` type. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better solution? Maybe my response class can have two generics, one for list of `item`s and another for a single `item`?

An approach in which the singular `<Job>` is converted to a list of `job`s with one element would also be interesting, but I'm not sure that can be a generic without modifying the XML response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Response")
public class Response {

    @XmlElement(name ="Status")
    private Status status;

    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name = "Job", type = Job.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "Jobs", type = Jobs.class),
    })
    private List<?> jobs;
}
```

Then Job would be:

```
public class Job {

    @XmlElement(name = "ID")
    private String id;
    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    private String name;
}
```

And Jobs:

```
public class Jobs {

    @XmlElement(name = "Job")
    private List<Job> jobs;
}
```

Update to answer on comment:

This is the cleanest way I could think of for handling these described payloads. The challenge is with the `<Jobs></Jobs>` being there only some times.

There is a way to do it without embedded list but it is messier. I will copy it below so you can decide if you like it, or better to get another cleaner solution.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Response")
public class Response {

    @XmlElement(name ="Status")
    private Status status;

    @XmlElement(name = "Job")
    private List<Job> jobs;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Jobs")
    @XmlElement(name = "Job")
    private List<Job> jobsWrapped;

}
```

Comment: This gives either a list of `List<Job>` (i.e. `list` of `list`s) or a `list` of `job`, correct ? is there a different way to approach this such as directly obtaining a `list<job>` in both scenarios, or, a `job` or `list<job>` instead (avoiding the nested list)?

Comment: @Zeruno This is the cleanest way I can think of. The problem is with `Jobs` being there only part of the time. There is an other way to do it, without nested list but its messier. Will update answer to include it

Comment: I was thinking to have my response class include two attributes, one a list of jobs and another a singular job, and then access one or the other accordingly, what about that?

Comment: @Zeruno yes indeed that was my solution - just posted :). You could then offer a single method to retrieve jobs based on your fields. Both versions work, you have to decide what you find preferable.

Comment: Yes, I see. Thanks very much for your edit! Your tip about having a single method is very helpful as well. Maybe what I would change for my use case is to have the singular element as a single object rather than a list of one element.

Comment: @Zeruno yes if the sample 2 is always a single job, the list is not necessary. Happy to help. cheers

Comment: If I may have other types rather than `job` and `jobs`, such as `person` and `persons`, how must the `@XmlElementWrapper` and its accompanying `@XmlElement` be changed to handle this generic case?

Comment: @Zeruno you could add the person and persons to the `@XmlElementWrapper`. You have to decide what makes sense to group together based on the items and the xml you receive. If you would have person(s) and job(s) maybe it would be better to have them as separate fields.

Comment: I would like to link two groups for a `List<Job>` with wrapper `Jobs` and a `List<Person>` with wrapper `Persons`. Is something such as the following possible?@XmlElementWrapper(name = {"Jobs", "Persons"})
@XmlElement(name = {"Job", "Person"});
private List<?> items;

Comment: @Zeruno I don't think it is possible, and not sure it should be either. Let's say this could work. What if you received payload `<Persons><Job>...</Job></Persons>`. I guess it would be invalid but how would you know and enforce it? Preferable to have a different field for persons. Of course then using the wrapper you would get 4 fields already. So imo it is best having the `@XmlElements` and define the valid variants of your payload as in the first example I posted.